# Which multivariate statistical method to use for qualitative AND quantitative data?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I'm just starting to learn about different types of multivariate statistics, but I'm having trouble figuring out which method is appropriate for my data.

My data is a mixture of quantitative and qualitative data. I'm making up an example dataset as below, as my real data includes many more rows and columns.

```
Sample ID  age  height  weight  gender  smoking  history of cancer
1          30   180     70      M       Y        N
2          25   175     80      M       N        N
3          50   180     60      M       Y        Y
4          35   170     NA      M       N        N
5          40   NA      65      M       N        Y
6          40   160     50      F       N        Y
7          20   165     70      F       Y        Y
8          35   150     50      F       NA       N
9          NA   170     65      F       Y        N
...
```

So each row is an individual patient, and I have columns that have quantitative data (age, height, weight) and qualitative/binary data (gender, whether they smoke or not, history of cancer).

My research question is to see what factors influence history of cancer. I'd like to know if any of my variables are more important to cancer than others, or if I can eliminate considering some variables that are unrelated to cancer. 
 I  initially thought about doing a PCA, but I'm not sure if PCA can be done with binary variables, and I've also heard that PCA doesn't produce good results if the data has too many zeros (or `NA` in this case). Anyone has any suggestions about which statistical methods I should look into?

Comment: Sounds like logistic regression to me

Comment: Agreed. Definitely logistic regression. In r the glm function would work. If you've never used logistic regression I would highly suggest finding someone who can help you; it's not the type of thing you can easily learn over a stack post.